# jquery: prevent default browser form submit behaviour but submit form with jquery?

Tags: jquery, forms, submit, form-submit

```
$('#search_form').submit(function(e) {
    //e.preventDefault();
    return false;
})
```

This works just fine to prevent form submission when pressing Enter.

However even I have this I want to submit the form with jquery if certain circumstances are true.

edit:

```
$('#search_form').submit(function(e) {
    return !!e.submit;
});

function ...

    if (e.keyCode == 13) {

        if (blablabla) {

            ... // do something

        } else {
            $('#search_form').submit({submit:true}); //doesn't work
            console.log('submitted'); //this does successfully get fired
        }

    }
```

If I press enter the form doesn't get submitted, but the log in in the console happens!

Comment: I think you'll need to post more code to troubleshoot this. As is, the syntax looks correct, so it probably isn't this part of the code that's causing the problem.

Comment: If you could re-create this on jsfiddle.net, I could help you out a lot better.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$('#search_form').submit(function(e) {
   if($('.errors').is(':visible')){
        e.preventDefault();
        // do something else here// some errors are visible :)
        return false; 
   }else{

   }
})
```

Comment: this doesn't work for me because I have two different functions! Like in my code above. And I cannot combine them.

Comment: u can trigger this function on a button click or somin or just simply wait for the submit button to be clicked

Answer (score 5):

By checking the type of `e.originalEvent` we can determine if human (type object) or script (type undefined) submitted the form:

```
$('#search_form').submit(function(e) {
    if (typeof e.originalEvent !== 'undefined') {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
})
```

Invoke a jquery trigger to submit the form:

```
$('#search_form').trigger('submit');
```