# prevent submitting form in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to add data to a selective cell of a table. I wrote this code in JavaScript.

```
var rowIndex = 10;
var colIndex = 5;
var dateTable = document.getElementById('timeTable');
dateTable.rows[rowIndex].cells[colIndex].innerHTML = "Su";
```

I wanted to use the same concept in jQuery as:

```
$('input[name=add_button]').click(function(e) {
    var dateTable = document.getElementById('timeTable');
    var rowIndex = $('[name=days]').val();
    var colIndex = $('[name=times]').val();
    var text = $('input[name = text]').val();
    dateTable.rows[rowIndex].cells[colIndex].innerHTML = text;
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

My problem is: `preventDefault()` method should prevent my form to be submitted. It is not preventing form submission. If I remove the      `dateTable.rows[rowIndex].cells[colIndex].innerHTML = text;` line, the form is not submitted. I think there is some problem with this particular line. Please help me sorting this. If there is better option available in jQuery please tell me. I shall be able to use the `colIndex` and `rowIndex` to find the position of the cell.

Thanks

Comment: can you post the html ? `colIndex` and `rowIndex` might not being set to what you expect and are in fact undefined. Did you see any error in console ?

Comment: are you getting any javascript error in firebug console...

Comment: @phobos: No I don't have any error in console

Comment: @MaheshSapkal: No. No errors..

Comment: convert `val()` to number. Hard to say you aren't getting errors...form might be submitting faster than errors show in console. Put `preventDefault at begining so if errors occur afterwards form won't submit

Comment: so instead of e.preventDefault(); use return false; and check if the form is getting submitted again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Add `return false;` in your `form tag` like

```
<form onsubmit="return false;" ......>

</form>
```

Also check you indexes that these are starting from `0 or 1`, if these are starting from `1` then you have to `decrease it by 1` before using it,

like `dateTable.rows[rowIndex-1].cells[colIndex-1].innerHTML = text;`

Actually when you click on `button` it will `prevent` its `default behavior`, not other elements behavior`(form in your case)`.

So, I think it is not possible to prevent your `form` here.

**Alternative Code** you can use:

```
$('form#myForm').on('submit',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var dateTable = document.getElementById('timeTable');
    var rowIndex = $('[name=days]').val();
    var colIndex = $('[name=times]').val();
    var text = $('input[name = text]').val();
    dateTable.rows[rowIndex].cells[colIndex].innerHTML = text;
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Do I have any jQuery alternative for this statement?

Comment: Check my answer once again, I have made some changes in it. Also refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5081674/jquery-prevent-default-browser-form-submit-behaviour-but-submit-form-with-jquer

Comment: This will not fulfill, what you needed?

Comment: Can you please continue this in http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27752/room-for-dibya-and-rohan-kumar